# Получить id только что созданной записи в таблице sql

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно получить id только что созданной записи в таблице sql с помощью php. 
Создаём запись в таблице тоже с помощью php.

Comment: *как можно получить id только что созданной записи в таблице sql* Ответ сильно зависит от того, с какой целью получается значение, где и как оно будет использовано. Но эта, практически самая важная, информация - увы, отсутствует в вопросе. Причём желательно отвечать пошире - описывая весь процесс, а не один его маленький этапчик. Потому как запросто может оказаться, что получать его вообще не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для `mysql`. Взято с [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

```
<?php
  $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
  if (!$link) {
    die('Ошибка соединения: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db('mydb');

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
  printf("Идентификатор последней вставленной записи %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

Для `mysqli`. Взято с [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php)

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* проверка соединения */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Соединение не установлено: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE myCity LIKE City");

$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
mysqli_query($link, $query);

printf ("ID новой записи: %d.\n", mysqli_insert_id($link));

/* закрытие соединения */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Всё хорошо, только mysql давно deprecated, нужно использовать mysqli

Comment: тег к вопросу `mysql`

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев дак это про СУБД, а не  библиотеку доступа. В тексте вопроса явно видно использование `mysqli`